# Question in using a set of ordered pairs and its union

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

The question became more verbose than I expected but it is really simple.

Let $A\subseteq X$, $A$ is non-empty, and $b \not\in A$.
Suppose that for all $x \in A$, there are two disjoint subsets of $X$ such that each of them has $x$ and $b$, respectively, that is
$$
\forall x \in A: \exists U, V \subseteq X: x\in U \land b \in V \land U\cap V = \varnothing
$$
Then, we can see that the union of all such $U$ contains $A$, while the intersection of all such $V$ has $b$. This style of proof stated in English is really what is done in many textbooks. But I want to utilize more mathematical tools to clarify for practice.

Now I am going to show this fact using a set of ordered pairs:
Let
$$
S = \{(U,V)\in \mathcal{P}(X)^2~|~U\cap A \neq \varnothing \land b\in V \land U \cap V = \varnothing\}
$$

where $\mathcal{P}$ denotes the power set. ($S$ is non-empty due to assumption.)

My question is whether the following expressions conform to the standard mathematical notation and the proofs are correct:

Claim 1:
$$ A \subseteq \bigcup_{(U,V)\in S}U$$

Proof: Let $x \in A$ be arbitrary. Then, there is $(U,V)\in S$ such that $x \in U$, which is obtained directly from the assumption.

Claim 2:
$$b \in \bigcap_{(U,V)\in S}V$$

It is a trivial result by definition.

To make the expressions more concise, I tried using a projection.

$$A \subseteq \bigcup_{B\in S}\pi_1 (B)$$

This is meant to be identical to Claim 1. And we can say that
$$
C =
\{\pi_1(B)~|~B\in S\}
=
\{N \subseteq X~|~ \exists B \in S : N = \pi_1(B)\}
$$
covers $A$.

Claim 3:

$$
\left(\bigcup_{B\in S}\pi_1(B) \right) \cap \left(\bigcap_{B\in S}\pi_2(B) \right) = \varnothing
$$

This is derived from the condition $U \cap V = \varnothing$ in the definition of $S$.

Comment: You could add the claim: 
$$\bigcup_{B\in S}\pi_1(B)=\{p\}^{\complement}\text{ and }\bigcap_{B\in S}\pi_2(B)=\{p\}$$

Comment: @drhab Thank you. Are the notations in this question acceptable?

Comment: Yes, the notation are okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notations are correct, though I prefer the simpler first version to the second: the projection functions are unnecessary clutter. However, what you’ve done symbolically is not the same as what you did in words at the top. Initially you said only that for each $x\in A$ there is (at least) **one** pair of sets $U,V\subseteq X$ such that $x\in U$, $b\in V$, and $U\cap V=\varnothing$. To capture this in symbols you might say that for each $x\in A$ there are sets $U_x,V_x\subseteq X$ such that $x\in U_x$, $b\in V_x$, and $U_x\cap V_x=\varnothing$. Your claims are then simply that

$$A\subseteq\bigcup_{x\in A}U_x$$

and

$$b\in\bigcap_{x\in A}V_x\,.$$

The set $\mathcal{S}$ that you defined contains much more than your introduction describes: it contains **every** pair $\langle U,V\rangle$ of subsets of $X$ such that $U$ contains some member of $A$, $b\in V$, and $U\cap V=\varnothing$. That’s fine if that’s what you wanted, but it is definitely not what you described at the beginning of the question. And as **drhab** pointed out, it allows a much stronger conclusion: the pair $\big\langle X\setminus\{b\},\{b\}\big\rangle$ is in $\mathcal{S}$, so

$$\bigcup_{\langle U,V\rangle\in\mathcal{S}}U=X\setminus\{b\}\supseteq A\,,$$

and

$$\bigcap_{\langle U,V\rangle\in\mathcal{S}}V=\{b\}\,.$$

Comment: Thank you! But I think the symbolic expression is identical to the description. I guess what you've pointed out is that I have to assign a choice function, right? But it is a matter of choice.

Comment: @Hermis14: You’re welcome! No, your symbolic expression is not identical to the description. The description promises only **one** pair of $U$ and $V$ for each $x\in A$; your definition of $\mathcal{S}$ captures **every possible** pair. Your description incorporates a choice function, which my notation made explicit by using subscripts to identify the point of $A$; your definition of $\mathcal{S}$ does not.

Comment: Oh, yes. Maybe there was a communication problem. I meant the symbolic expression at the top, not $S$.

Comment: @Hermis14: Ah, okay; yes, that matches the verbal description.